# Detection of focus change events when `WM_KILLFOCUS` and `WM_SETFOCUS` do not arrive

Tags: windows, menu, focus, contextmenu, keyboard-events

For smoother interaction of my application with the user I need to know when my program can see **the whole flow** of keyboard events from the user, and when this flow is interrupted.  I’m testing my approach on a simple top-level with only a (subclassed) Rich Edit control inside.  It turns out that checking for `WM_KILLFOCUS` and `WM_SETFOCUS` messages *is not enough*: these messages do not arrive when the text edit window wants to show menus.  These menus “eat” the keypresses/keyreleases, but no “expected” message notifies me about this situation.

For the right-mouse-button menu I thought that monitoring `WM_INITMENU`, `WM_INITMENUPOPUP`, `WM_UNINITMENUPOPUP`, `WM_ENTERMENULOOP`, `WM_EXITMENULOOP`, `WM_SYSCOMMAND`, `WM_COMMAND`, `WM_MENUCOMMAND`, `WM_MENUSELECT`, `WM_ACTIVATE`, `WM_ACTIVATEAPP`, `WM_MENUCHAR` would give me “plenty of warnings” about what is going to happens.  To my surprise, only `WM_MENUCOMMAND` (“marked as failure”) is received!  Well, very strange — but I can live with it.

However, I cannot detect `Alt`-tapping (which moves the focus to “the icon for window’s menu” of the main window) *at all*: the next key-down event is (typically¹⁾) eaten, and **no mentioned message** arrives…  For example, `Alt`-tap `f` gives key-down and key-up for `Alt`, but only key-up for `f`.

> ¹⁾ “Typical” since pressing *appropriate* keys (say, down-arrow) in this situation visualizes the “window’s menu”.  However “a random key” would “cancel the focus stealing”. — However, the price is that one key-down event disappears.

So now **my questions**: the show-stopper for *now* is the detection of the focus moving to the icon for window’s menu.  Can an application detect this moment?  The second question is to understand why for the context menu (e.g., tapping on the `Apps` key) I do not get anything before the `MENUCOMMAND` event.

**Finally**: eventually, (if it works) I would prefer my code to be in a library — so it would need cohabitation with a multitude of ways.to “manage the window”.  What I discussed above shows that (apparently) in Windows *there is a way* to steal focus without notifications.  This means that there may be “other situations” — others than two types of menus discussed above — which would give the same kind of trouble to my code.  So my third **Question:** is there a robust way to work around such situations?  (And: how such situations are implemented via Windows APIs?!)